# ¿Como navegar en la misma pagina sin usar el scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

La idea principal de crear esta funcion es no usar el scroll vertical , y apartir de un evento click de un boton u otro control ejecutar dicha funcion y  navegar a una etiqueta `<div>` o  una etiqueta  `<a>`  especifica que esta en la misma pagina.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?, si entiendo bien, ¿deseas una función que muestre un `div` (el cual está oculto) al seleccionar un elemento `<a>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para navegar dentro de una misma página debes usar un elemento con id (el objetivo) y un anchor (`<a>`) que apunta a dicho elemento, de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="#id_del_elemento">Ir a tal parte</a>

...

<div id="id_del_elemento"> ... </div>
```

El elemento destino puede ser cualquier elemento.

```html
<a href="#elid">Ir a el ID</a>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p id="elid">este es el elemento</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
```

Para hacer lo mismo en javascript, puedes hacer lo siguiente: Aqui el truco es que estableces el hash de la url en el valor del id del elemento, igual que si lo editaras a mano en la barra de la url del navegador.

```
function moverseA(idDelElemento) {
    location.hash = "#" + idDelElemento;
}
```

y la usas

```
moverseA("id_del_elemento"); // sin el #
```

```js
function moverseA(idDelElemento) {
  location.hash = "#" + idDelElemento;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moverseA('elid')">Ir a el ID</button>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p id="elid">este es el elemento</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
```

Comment: Ok..con  esas lineas marco el objetivo..muy bien lo entiendo...y solo faltan las lineas Javacsript

Comment: +1 porque entendiste mejor el problema que yo :)

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC he editado la respuesta

Answer (score 4):

La [respuesta de rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20190/250) es lo que quieres. Voy a dejar una alternativa con Javascript (usando jQuery) en la que se anima el scroll de manera que no se da un salto al elemento objetivo, sino que se hace una pequeña transición al moverse usando [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```js
function saltarA(id, tiempo) {
  var tiempo = tiempo || 1000;
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, tiempo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="javascript:saltarA('#destino')">Saltar a destino</a></p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>0</p>
<p id="destino">Destino!</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>0</p>
```

Comment: Como seria para lo q nesecito con jquery , sin usar un temporizador solo qu navegue a donde se indique??

Comment: Le puedes quitar el tiempo. Si te fijas yo le pongo un tiempo de 1 segundo (1000 milisegundos) si no se especifica nada (y se llama sin temporizador alguno en el código de arriba), pero lo puedes hacer sin tiempo `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top });` (aunque internamente jQuery usará 400 milisegundos)

Comment: muchas gracias...